# How to calculate difference from a reference point on a cyclic scale?

Tags: r, difference

I'm stuck on how to calculate error for a parameter fitting when the scale of the parameter is cyclic in nature.

For example, parameter "A" can vary between 0 and 1, which represent fraction of a year (i.e. 0 = Jan 1st, 0.25 = Apr 1st, 0.5 = Jul 1st, 0.75 = Oct 1st, and 1.0 = Jan 1, etc.).

How can I measure difference from a reference point. In this case, I would like difference to be min/max +- 0.5.

Here's an example where reference point is Apr 1st:

```
ref <- 0.25 # Apr 1st
val <- c(0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.95) # what is the difference from these values to ref
minval <- 0
maxval <- 1

# expected output
c(-0.15, 0.05, 0.45, -0.3)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
((val-ref + .5) %% 1) - .5
# [1] -0.15  0.05  0.45 -0.30
```

Comment: And if, for example, you were working in degrees on a circle, you'd just substitute in `180` and `360` for `.5` and `1`.

Comment: Perfect - much easier that what I was trying with arc lengths etc. Cheers